# How to implement a 2 into every 3 hits to return a true?

Tags: c++, algorithm, probability

I am trying to implement a generic algorithm for 2 in every 5 hit will return a true.2 is the allowed and 5 is the hits.  In short this means if a function is called 5 times 2 of those times it will return true otherwise it will be a false. This is my try and it seems to be incorrect. Any suggestions on how I can fix it or if there is a better way to solve this ?

```
//2 in every 3 hits will return a true.
int hitlimit = 3;
int allowedlimit = 2;
int allowedTracker = 0;
int hitsTracker = 0;
bool test()
{
   hitsTracker++;
   if(allowedTracker < allowedlimit && hitsTracker < hitlimit) 
   {
     allowedTracker++;
     if(allowedTracker >= allowedlimit) 
     {
        allowedTracker = 0 ; 
        hotstracker =  0;
     }
     return true;    
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Could you show some examples of desired results? And contrast against the results you get with the shown code? I ask because I have no idea what your goal is. "2 into every 3 hits" is unclear to me.

Comment: I would appreciate it if some one could tell me why its voted to be closed

Comment: @Yunnosch it basically means if its states 2 in every 5 returns a true. If a function is called 5 times 2 of those times it will return true otherwise it will be a false

Comment: This doesn't look like Java code.  The `java` tag seems inappropriate.

Comment: removed the `java` tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand that you want to generate a deterministic sequence of `allowedLimit` ones followed by `hitlimit - allowedlimit` zeros. This is a periodic sequence that can be easily calculated from the current index:

```
int hitlimit = 3;
int allowedlimit = 2;
int hitsTracker = 0;
bool test() {
    return hitsTracker++ % hitlimit < allowedlimit;
}
```

Comment: This totally works. Thanks